# React props is passed, but only render() reads props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I couldn't find a related situation to mines, however my problem I am having a common error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.

Weird part is, this error is occurring only for the method I defined above `render()`.

Inside of `render()` I am able to have access without errors though. React dev tools shows I even have access to props.

Code below:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthService from '../../utils/authentication/AuthService'
import withAuth from '../../utils/authentication/withAuth'

const Auth = new AuthService()

class HomePage extends Component {

    handleLogout() {
        Auth.logout()
        this.props.history.replace('/login')
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.history)
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome {this.props.user.userId}</h2>
                </div>
                <p className="App-intro">
                    <button type="button" className="form-submit" onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withAuth(HomePage)
```

Edit: Apologies. I don't want to cause a confusion either, so I will add that I am also using `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`to avoid `this` binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your method `handleLogout` has it's own context. In order to pass the `this` value of the class to your method have to do one of two things:

1) Bind it inside the constructor of the class:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this)
}
```

2) You declare your `handleLogout` method as an arrow function

```
handleLogout = () => {
  console.log(this.props)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this isn't bound in non es6 I believe.  So you could either bind it with a constructor, or you may be able to get away with an es6 type function

```
handleLogout = () => {
    Auth.logout()
    this.props.history.replace('/login')
}
```

I can't try this, but you could also do a

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Don't call this.setState() here!

  this.handleLogOut= this.handleLogOut.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.bind` on your click handler.

```
<button type="button" className="form-submit" onClick={this.handleLogout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
```